# How to get search display item on button action when searching in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableView` with `searchDisplayController` and a button in table view as contentView.

I am displaying an array with dictionaries in table view. When i search with searchBar, I am getting a search item from the array.

Now what i want is, when i search with the searchBar i want to get that object on button action.

Button action code

```
-(void)getClickObject:(UIButton *)sender
{
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *path = [listOfProductsTable indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

In above method i`am getting index object in table view

```
-(void) filterForSearchText:(NSString *) text scope:(NSString *) scope
{
[searchResultArry removeAllObjects];
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",text]; 
searchResultArry = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[nameArry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate]];

 }
 -(BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
 {
 [self filterForSearchText:searchString scope:[[[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] selectedScopeButtonIndex] ]];

return YES;
 }

-(BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
[self filterForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];

return YES;
}
```

I want to get cell object on button action when searching in table view

Comment: Post some code to look further.

Comment: Look like your code is incomplete. 

Q1, Did you tried logging the path to confirm it as correct?
Q2, After getting path, there is no code to query the array?
Q2, When you enter the searchterm, your table is displaying only the search result or not ?

Comment: searching perfectly working. I want to get search result object on button action method when searching in table view

Comment: Could you please add the following method that you use?
 -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a button tag value unique to the cell contents,then get the button instance using `viewWithTag` method as

```
UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3];//here 3 is the tag i set for button in cell
```

and you have the button instance to work with